Google Classroom API Invitations not sending emails
Google classroom invite emails are not being sent. The user does not receive emails or even show up in their google classroom home page. However when I check the people tab they are there. It shows the user and it says (invited) when I ask the user however they say that they didn't receive any emails and its not showing up in their home page for google classroom.
I expected google to send an invite to the user I specified, it doesnt send an email.
Here is my code:
def create_classroom_course(request):
    # Ensure the user is authenticated
    if 'credentials' not in request.session:
        return redirect('oauth2_login')

    # Load user credentials from session
    credentials = Credentials(**request.session['credentials'])
    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=credentials)  
    try:
        user_info = service.userProfiles().get(userId='me').execute()
        user_id = user_info.get('id')  # The authenticated user's ID
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error fetching user details: {e}")  
  
    course_data = {
        'ownerId': 'me',  # This sets the owner as the current authenticated user
    }
 
    # Use course data from session
    course_data = request.session.get('course_data', {
        'name': 'Default Course Name',
        'section': 'Default Section',
        'descriptionHeading': 'Default Heading',
        'description': 'Default Description',
        "courseState": "PROVISIONED",
    })
    
    try:
        # Make the API call to create the course
        course = service.courses().create(body=course_data).execute()
        courseInviteID = course['id']
        updatingID = Course.objects.filter(id = request.session.get('courseID')['courseID']).first()
        
        invitation_data = {
        'userId': 'test@gmail.com',  # The email of the user to invite
        'courseId': courseInviteID,  # The ID of the course
        'role': 'STUDENT'  # or 'TEACHER' depending on the role
        }    
        try:
            invitation = service.invitations().create(body=invitation_data).execute()
            logging.info(f"Invitation sent: {invitation}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error sending invitation: {e}")
     #   invitation = service.invitations().create(body=invitation_data).execute()
    
        
        if updatingID is not None:
            # Get the new courseLink from the request (assuming it's sent in the body)
            new_course_link = course['alternateLink']  # or request.data if using Django REST Framework
            new_courseID = course['id']
            # Update the courseLink field
            updatingID.courseLink = new_course_link
            updatingID.googleCourseID = new_courseID
            # Save the changes to the database
            updatingID.save()
        
        return JsonResponse(course, status=201)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error creating course: {e}")
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=500)

**edit uploaded my whole code.

Can you complete your code so that the readers can understand what's happening on the execution of your code?

Have they check their spam folder?

@LimeHusky uploaded the whole code now. and yes, they have checked their spam folders. I also tried checking mine, but i don't see any invites as well. When I use the google API explorer to create an Invite, it works, the user gets an invite. I use the same requests and the same data being passed but for some reason, no email invites are being sent.

Have you tried checking print() on each execution so that you can check where you made an error? Additionally what are the import libraries you added?

I did, i actually have logging all over the code, but I decided to remove them from the code here. But everything shows up in the console, it gives me an invitation instance after the API call. Just that no emails are appearing, the code for the creation of the classroom even works fine as I see the classroom being created.
